# Adding a Container to Podman Network and Enabling cURL Access

Tags: docker, fastapi, podman

I wish to add a container to podman network and accessible from curl, how should I do that?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

cmd ["uvicorn", "server:app", "--host", "127.0.0.1", "--port", "5000", "--log-level", "trace"]
```

server.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world"
```

Build

`podman build -t my_app .`

Run

`podman run --restart always -dp 9001:5000 --network mynetwork --name my_app my_ap`

When I run `curl localhost:9001` it just hang without receiving a "Hello world" as response.

Comment: Try without `--network mynetwork` that means you aren't attached to localhost.

Comment: In standard Docker and presumably also in Podman, setting `--host 127.0.0.1` means the service will be unreachable from outside its own container.  You almost always need to set `--host 0.0.0.0` if that isn't the default.